# why my first object is bigger than the others on my grid CSS

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

hi I'm trying to make a gallery display whit some images for a art gallery , I am using CSS grids I'm new to this I'm doing well I only have one question and I'm kind of stuck there , I dont know why wen im playng whit some padding and size parameters it affects more the first object of the grid display tan the other one, like the first one is bigger than the others ,

[image: that .wrpper don't listen to me]

Comment: code is much better than screenshots!

Comment: sorry about it its the first time i post a screenshot i will take it in consideration

Comment: Please provide code or live link

Comment: @d3fco could you please edit the question and paste your code?

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
grid-template-rows: 30%;
```

could solve the problem.

```
.wrapper{
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 65px;
  display: grid;
  float: right;
  grid-template-columns: 30%;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  grid-row-gap: 50px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/21vbLaow/

Comment: yess it iss, thank you verry much for the quick help , im so noob haha

Comment: i'm not familiar with grid template as well. :)